# How to handle data denormalization in Firestore using Firebase Cloud functions when offline

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, nosql, offline

I want to keep an account balance in Firestore always up to date, depending on the newest balance document in a subcollection.

Let's say I have the following database structure:

```
- accounts (collection)
  |
   - accountA (document)
     |- fields:
     |   - name: "account a"
     |   - currentBalance: 1000  <----------- This one will be updated by cloud functions
     |                                                            ^
     |- balances (collection)                                     |
        |                                                         |
        |- A (document)                                           |
        |   - fields:                                             |
        |     - balance: 1000   -----------------------------------
        |     - date: 10.10.2020
        |- B (document)
            - fields:
              - balance: 500
              - date: 09.10.2020
```

So I have an accounts collection, that holds documents of accounts.
Each account has a name and a current balance.

However, the balance is not directly written to the account, but updated by a cloud function.

Let's say a user adds a new balance under the account, with a newer date (today).

The cloud function then checks on write to that balances collection, checks all documents, takes the one with the latest date, and writes that balance to the balance from the account.

This works great and all, but now let's go **offline**.

The user adds a new balance with date of today as 2000, but then nothing happens, because obviously, the cloud function can't trigger. So far that all makes sense.

---

**Question**

What is the best way to handle this?

1. Have the client automatically apply the check for latest date and update the balance manually, and then if ever it goes online, it will just get latest data from the cloud?
2. Have a different data structure altogether? But then data duplication/denormalization seems to be the common case in Firestore, and offline seems to break all this logic.

Is there a best practice I'm not aware of or do we have to duplicate all the cloud function logic on the client side and check if we're offline or online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

When the user is offline I wouldn't attempt to recalculate the balance because you're opening yourself up to:

1. Angry users who see a different balance in their offline app than when online and will accuse you of all sorts of things.
2. Potential exploits caused by users performing actions offline and then reconnecting.

My recommendation based on your description would be to display the balance as grayed out with an "(Out of Sync)" message if the last retrieved balance is older than the latest transaction.  If the user needs to perform actions that would subtract from that balance, I would use the last retrieved value as the source of truth.

**Question 2**

Regarding database structure what you have is fine, but I personally prefer a flatter structure where you'd have:

```
/accounts
  /{accountId}

/ledger
  /{txId}

/balances
  /{accountId}
```

The reasoning is primarily for easier maintenance because it's easy to delete a parent collection and forget to delete its subcollections and documents, which will continue to live on invisibly racking up costs.  The deeper your nests the worst worse it gets.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts especially on the implications on point 1. However, I feel having out of sync balance will be very bad user experience. It's not an banking app, more like a personal overview of your own accounts where you add your balances and maybe transactions. But there is no real account connections involved or sending money